# Nodejs Websockets work Locally but not on Server

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, express-ws

I am attempting to use the express-ws library with a nodejs server being hosted on gcloud. I'm using some basic starter code and it works when I run the code locally. However, if I try to connect when the code is being hosted on the web I receive an error. I am using a chrome extension to test the web sockets and it is able to access other echo servers. What is it about hosting the code in an app engine instance that is causing this issue?

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');


var app = express();
var http = require('http');
app.server = http.createServer(app);
require('express-ws')(app, app.server);

app.ws('/echo', function(ws, req) {
  ws.on('message', function(msg) {
    ws.send(msg);
  });
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});


module.exports = app;
```

I have also modified /bin/www to be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('eidalon-queue:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = app.server;

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
```

These modifications were from this [issue request](https://github.com/HenningM/express-ws/issues/104) where express-ws does not work with express-generator.

Comment: Have you tried to create [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/creating-firewalls)?

Comment: Currently, I just have the default firewall rule that allows all IPs

Comment: Can you show the error on both sides?

Comment: The client I'm trying to connect from just gives a 'Failed to Connect' Error. The gCloud console and the Error tracking don't provide any printout associated with a ws:// or wss:// request. However, http:// requests do throw an error (TypeError: app.set is not a function)

Comment: Wild guess: Are you using insecure (http:// or ws://)  to connect when it is in the cloud? Does the cloud version support insecure or are you required to use secure (https:// or wss://) in order for it to connect?

Comment: I've tried both wss and ws

Comment: The problem was the type of app engine instance I was using. It would appear only flexible instances of App engine support web sockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Websockets are only supported by [Flexible Instances](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/introducing-websockets-support-for-app-engine-flexible-environment) of App Engine and not Standard. The standard environment just passes back an invalid response code to the handshake. Converting my project from standard to Flexible fixed the issue.